# PostgreSQL - Trigger Each Statement - How to get Query statement

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm doing a trigger Each Statement and I would like to access the Query Statement that triggered the trigger. Is this possible ?

Something like this:

`update table_1 where id> 300;`

This query triggers an update event in table table_1 and this event triggers a function associated with the update trigger. This trigger is configured as Each Statement and inside the trigger I would like to do something like this:

`raise info 'Query Statement that fired this trigger:%', last_query();`

Would this be possible?

Thank you!

Julio

Comment: I have not found a system function or view to do this in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function [`current_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html).